# Update statement inside oracle stored procedure is not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have one simple update statement inside oracle stored procedure. Its executing successfully but its not updating the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdateSourceLog
( SourceLogId IN NUMBER, TotalRowCount IN INT,Status IN VARCHAR)

AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE  SourceLog
        SET     Status = Status,
                TotalRowCount = TotalRowCount,
                EndTime = SYSDATE
        WHERE   SourceLogId = SourceLogId;
        COMMIT;
END;
```

I have tried with changing the perameter name different from column name. Then also Its not working. 
And I have tried with anonymous block. I'm not able to find out the isue. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is a bad practice to give parameters the same name as table columns.

So you should change it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdateSourceLog
( p_SourceLogId IN NUMBER, p_TotalRowCount IN INT,p_status IN VARCHAR)

AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE  SourceLog
        SET     Status = p_status,
                TotalRowCount = p_TotalRowCount,
                EndTime = SYSDATE
        WHERE   SourceLogId = p_SourceLogId;
        COMMIT;
END;
```

Because for now, most likely, Oracle understands it as column names and just update column to value from this column (no sense at all)

Comment: I have changed the perameter name and tried to execute.But still it didnt update the table.I'm not able to find out the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have rows with `SourceLogId = p_SourceLogId;`?

Comment: And how did you execute this procedure?

Comment: You might want to add an exception handler to report on any errors which occur. I'd put something like: `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM); ` between the `COMMIT;` and `END;`. Best of luck.

Comment: BEGIN UpdateSourceLog (83,100,'s'); END;  I have SourceLogId =83 in the table

Comment: Are you sure your procedure compiled without errors? And how do you check new values?

Comment: Another solution is to "namespace" the column names and parameters like this: `SourceLog.sStatus = UpdateSourceLog.Status`

Comment: so far this procedure should work. in my opinion the commit should not be done inside the procedure because the caller will not expect it. Or rename your procedure to UpdateSourceLogAndCommit()  :-)  Consider to declare it with `pragma autonomous_transaction`.