# I want to update table column from compare to other table column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to update column with this code

```
DECLARE  
   EMP_id EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID1%TYPE;  
   EMP_REST EMPLOYEES.WEEK_REST%TYPE;

   CURSOR C_EMP is  
      SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID1, WEEK_REST FROM EMPLOYEES 
      WHERE SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX = 103001;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN C_EMP;  
   LOOP  
      FETCH C_EMP into EMP_id, EMP_REST ;
      UPDATE PAY_IN_OUT2
  SET OT = 8
WHERE 
 EMP_CODE = EMP_id 
AND ATT_DATE IN (SELECT GAZZETED_DATE FROM GAZZETED_DAYS);  
      EXIT WHEN C_EMP%notfound;      
      
END LOOP;  
CLOSE C_EMP;  
END;
```

it runs and message to me procedure complete but not updating the column where I am doing wrong please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update statement inside oracle stored procedure is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135799/update-statement-inside-oracle-stored-procedure-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
MERGE INTO PAY_IN_OUT2 e
    USING  EMPLOYEES h
    ON (e.EMP_CODE = h.EMPLOYEE_ID1 and 
    SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX = 103001 and
    ATT_DATE IN (SELECT GAZZETED_DATE FROM GAZZETED_DAYS)
   )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.OT =8 ;
```

or use this one:

```
update PAY_IN_OUT2 ea 
set OT = 8
where  ATT_DATE IN (SELECT GAZZETED_DATE FROM GAZZETED_DAYS)  
and EMP_CODE in (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID1 FROM EMPLOYEES 
      WHERE SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX = 103001
        );
```

I removed the unused field `WEEK_REST`.

Comment: Dear it compiled but not worked and not update